# Re-using (putting back into service) a Craftsman 33 gal 165 PSI air compressor

Tags: air-compressor

I own a Craftsman 33 gal 165 psi upright air compressor that during a move we emptied the air out using the 'ring pin' at top. It has been sitting for over a year in the garage and now I need to start using it on occasion. I'm new to using air compressors but I can learn. What is the best way (steps involved) to put this unit back in service and maintaining it? Thank you!

[image: front label]

[image: 33 gal air compressor]

Comment: Wait, you clearly don't know the bottom valve *exists*. How many years have you been using this compressor without ever using the bottom valve???

Comment: i would be nervous pressurizing a tank that had standing water in it for some time.

Answer (score 2):

It's an oilless compressor, so plug it in, turn it on, dump the water out of the bottom of the tank daily (which is what the drain on the bottom of the tank is there for. That's also the preffered way to drain all air (and collected water) from the tank, rather than pulling on the overpressure-safety-valve ring.)

Vacuum or blow dust off it so that it can cool itself, change the intake filter once in a while.

There's nothing else to maintain here, until something breaks. Then it's often a tossup as to whether replacement parts cost more than a new compressor.

If you can't find your owner's manual there appears to be a terrible scan of it on some site other than the Sears one, while the Sears site promises a manual link but does not actually deliver one.

Comment: Just add that it needs draining on a regular basis, maybe weekly, from that tap underneath, otherwise water will build up inside, which will eventually find its way into any air tools you'll use shortening their lives quite a bit.

Comment: Rusts out the tank, too, which is one reason I already suggested daily (as does the owner's manual.)

Comment: Your and my suggestion must have crossed. Didn't see it when I commented.

Comment: Maybe consider getting it pressure tested to ensure the tank wasn't compromised by any water that was in there while it was sitting. Safety valves won't help when the tank fails at pressures below what the valve is rated to release at.

Answer (score 1):

Compressors don't need much upkeep but they do need to have their water drained regularly.

As you may know, air contains water. This is called "humidity".  Hotter air can hold more water than cold air (that's why air conditioners drip water).

In a compressor, compressing the air heats the air too, so it can probably hold all the water in the air.  However, this quickly cools off because we really want it to cool off, and we have cooling fins and "intercoolers" on the compressor to do just that, plus the side of the tank will radiate heat.  As the air cools off, water condenses out of it (much like the air conditioner).

In fact, the compressed-air cycle is very similar to air conditioning - you may notice the blasts of air are cold, and your air tool will turn freezing cold as you use it. Yeah, air would work as a refrigerant lol (but it would make the A/C lines bigger).

Anyway, that means the air in your tank (at that pressure) will be 100% relative humidity and moisture will fall out of it into the bottom of the tank.  **This moisture must be drained**.

If it is not drained regularly, it will rust the steel tank and cause an explosive failure of the tank eventually.

So since you did not know to drain it, you need to drain it now.  Notice how much water comes out of it, and notice how rusty it is.  If it's a lot of water and a lot of rust, somebody should really ultrasound the bottom of that tank to make sure it hasn't lost significant thickness.  If not, you dodged a bullet.

Generally every day after finishing with the air, you should drain the tank to remove water.  Now some people like to don safety goggles and a face shield and throw it wide open just to see it blast. Or you can just crack it and go do something else. I like that one.  Take a moment to observe how much water is coming out.  Once the tank depressurizes, the air inside should be relatively low humidity and hopefully will absorb the remaining water that did not drain, thus drying the tank completely.

Comment: What category of company would one look to in searching for this sort of ultrasound service/air compressor service company?